# Wait for complex function to finish (with multiple ajax calls) before calling ajax function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, deferred

Bear with me here, I'll try to explain the problem as clearly as I can.

from the simplest task, my first task is to, call this create() function, which includes 2 ajax calls inside it

```
 popup().create('Zip code is required to add product to cart')

create: function (popupTitle) {
                let self = this;
                let options = {
                    type: 'popup',
                    responsive: true,
                    modalClass: 'zip-modal',
                    title: popupTitle,
                    buttons: [{
                        text: $.mage.__('Apply'),
                        class: 'action primary',
                        click: function () {
                            if (self.validateZip(self.zipForm)) {
                               ----------> self.getCatalog(); ------------<
                                this.closeModal()
                            }
                        }
                    }],

                    closed: function () {
                        if (self.zipInput.val() === '') {
                            $.cookie('zip_code_set', 'not_set', {path: '/'})
                            self.lightbox.show();
                        }
                    }
                };
                modal(options, this.popup);
                this.popup.modal('openModal');
            
        },
```

first one being. specified getCatalog() function

```
        getCatalog: function () {
            let self = this;
            let value = this.zipInput.val();

            fullScreenLoader.startLoader();

            storage.post(
                url.build('rest/V1/zip/getCatalog'),
                JSON.stringify({
                    zipCode: value
                }),
                true,
                'application/json'
            ).done(
                function (response) {
                    ---------> self.validateCatalog(); -----------<
                    fullScreenLoader.stopLoader();
                },
            )
        },
```

which creates an ajax post request, and in it's.done() function also has another function which does another ajax get request

```
        validateCatalog: function () {
            fullScreenLoader.startLoader();

            storage.get(
                url.build('rest/V1/zip/getCategory'),
            ).done(
                function (response) {
                    customerData.set('categoryMenu', response[0].categoryMenu);
                    fullScreenLoader.stopLoader();
                    // window.location.reload();
                },
            )
        },
```

thing is after all this happens basically after create() function, I have to call another function which does ajax request, but it has to wait before all this create() function finishes and only then fire off, ways which I found that this could be possibly achieved looks like are $.Deferred and also callbacks but I can't get it to work either, in every attempt, it always fires off this function with ajax request before create() function is done with all it's ajax requests. any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This may well be better as a comment but I don't have enough rep to make comments yet.

There's probably a more efficient way but the simplest way I can think of would be to use a boolean variable that's set to true when the final ajax call completes & just have an interval checking the value...something like:

```
bAllDone = false;
// In final ajax .done
bAllDone = true;

callCreate = setInterval(function(){
   if(bAllDone){
      clearInterval(callCreate);
      create()
   }
},100);
```